# Using QpushButton to switch the images displaying in a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qpushbutton

I am a beginner. One part of my project is using QpushButton to switch the images which are displaying in a QLabel, first step I will open a folder and set a filter for .jpg and then save their path in a QString list. Here is my code:

```
void data_labeling::on_next_clicked()
{
    int i = 0;

    QString filename1 = "/home/jin/test/test.jpg";
    QFileInfo fileinfo1(filename1);
    QString foldername1 = fileinfo1.path();

    QDir dir(foldername1);
    dir.setNameFilters(QStringList()<< "*.jpeg" << "*.jpg");
    QStringList images = dir.entryList();

    QImage image(images[i]);

    QPixmap::fromImage(image);
    int w = ui->face_pic->width();
    int h = ui->face_pic->height();
    ui->face_pic->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(h,w,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}
```

There are so many images in this folder,I know why I failed, since every time I press the button which is using the function, the integer I always equal to 0. So anyone can give me a suggestion?

Comment: I understand that what you want to do is change the image that is displayed every time you press a button, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes you are correct

Comment: @eyllanesc ok I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select the folder I recommend using the [`QFileDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) class through the [`getExistingDirectory()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) method. Another improvement is to generate a function that only takes care of placing a new image.

One more note is that `entryList()` returns the names of the filter files, but this is not the full path, to get this we use the `filePath()` function.

***.h**

```
private:
    QDir dir;
    QStringList images;
    int index;

    void updatePixmap();
```

*.cpp

```
{//constructor
    ui->setupUi(this);

    index = 0;
    QString dirname = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Select directory", "/home/jin/test/");
    if(!dirname.isEmpty()){
        dir = QDir(dirname);
        dir.setNameFilters(QStringList()<< "*.jpeg" << "*.jpg");
        images = dir.entryList();
    }

    updatePixmap();
}


void data_labeling::on_next_clicked()
{
    updatePixmap();
}

void data_labeling::updatePixmap()
{
    if(images.count() > 0){
        int w = ui->face_pic->width();
        int h = ui->face_pic->height();

        QImage image(dir.filePath(images[index]));

        ui->face_pic->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(h,w,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
        index  = (index +1) % images.count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, actually I have another QpushuButton to open the QFileDialog to select the image, then I use a QtextBrowser to show the image path, so the image path here is reading from the QtextBrowser

Comment: I tried your code but in the dialog the images can not be opened, they all gray and can not be click-able.